# create a cocossharp project in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio, cocossharp

Im new in xamarin studio and im trying to create a cocosproject following the official guide, but this document is not very clear and my project have so many errors.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/cocossharp/#nuget

I've created a xamarin.form with IOS, android and PCL as guide say

I've  added the cocosSharp packages to IOS and Android projects

BUT

if i don't add the cocosSharp package to PCL target, the cocos Classes cant be found by the code

And if I try to add the cocosSharp packages to PCL, console show this

Could not install package 'CocosSharp 1.7.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

i tried to change the targetFramework but this don't help me

if someone work with cocosSharp and xamarin studio V6, please how can i solve this ?

Or how can i add the add in of cocosSharp in Galery like in previous versions of xamarin ?

This is the code in a ContentPage, Cocos Classes can't be found

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Hello ContentPage" }
            }
        };
    }

    void CreateTopHalf(Grid grid)
    {
        // This hosts our game view.
        var gameView = new CocosSharpView()
        {
            // Notice it has the same properties as other XamarinForms Views
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            // This gets called after CocosSharp starts up:
            ViewCreated = HandleViewCreated
        };
        // We'll add it to the top half (row 0)
        grid.Children.Add(gameView, 0, 0);
    }

    void HandleViewCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var gameView = sender as CCGameView;
        if (gameView != null)
        {
            // This sets the game "world" resolution to 100x100:
            gameView.DesignResolution = new CCSizeI(100, 100);
            // GameScene is the root of the CocosSharp rendering hierarchy:
            gameScene = new GameScene(gameView);
            // Starts CocosSharp:
            gameView.RunWithScene(gameScene);
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

just figured this out myself. It's true that there's no matching build for Profile 259. Try 151 instead:

1. Right click the PCL project in your solution explorer
2. Click 'Options'
3. Click 'General' on the left hand side.
4. Change the Current Profile to "PCL 4.6 - Profile151"
5. Click 'OK'.

Now you'll need to refresh the Nuget Packages so that Xamarin Forms can redownload the right profile. Afterward you can successfully add CocosSharp.Forms.