# Failed to add cocossharp.forms in visual studio 2017

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, cocossharp

I created a xamarin.forms project in visual studio 2017, then I tried to add cocossharp.forms using nuget and I got this error:

**Could not install package 'CocosSharp 1.7.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**

It seems I got the same error in [create a cocossharp project in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195764/create-a-cocossharp-project-in-xamarin), but the answer provided is for xamarin studio and I don't know how to apply that to visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to put this in here for future reference, since I couldn't find an answer for visual studio anywhere.

You have to open the project's **.csproj** file as text and change the targeted profile to **151** and the targeted framework version to **4.6**

Here is what the lines you need to update look like:

[image: here]